# Wacom is no longer working on Linux

Tags: linux, wacom

I am getting this error when plugging in my wacom tablet.

```
usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 14, error -32
usb 1-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I don't believe the cable is the problem as I am connecting directly to my computer.  The tablet works fine as a pointer device on an Apple.

I have the kernel configured for wacom as well as the xf86 wacom input driver installed.  I don't have any other USB devices plugged in, so I am expecting it to work.